Laundry Room Cabinets/Shelving Additions
I have a 66”-wide by 8’-tall wall in my laundry room where I’d like to install two cabinets and two shelves. The wall has only two studs, spaced 16” apart. These additions need to support detergent, cleaning supplies, and linens.
Proposed Plan:

Add a full-length steel flat bar across the wall to anchor the cabinets and shelves. The bar will be attached to the studs with screws and secured with toggle bolts where studs are unavailable.
Each cabinet will have 4 toggle bolts for wall support and 3 screws into a single stud located on the side walls of each cabinet for additional stability.
The middle shelf will use 3 toggle bolts, and the bottom shelf will have 2 screws and 3 toggle bolts.

Questions:

Is this a good approach?
How many toggle bolts should I use for optimal support?
Are there alternative mounting options I should consider for better stability?

Here’s an illustration of the setup. Green represents room corners, white for cabinets, brown for shelves, and red for studs.


It's not clear what a "steel flat bar" would be or how you'd use it, or how your cabinets mount. Please revise to explain better. I'm also curious how your wall is lacking studs over such a wide area.

The steel is not necessary, and will definitely be harder to work with: You'll have to drill approximately 1/2" holes in the steel for your average toggle bolt, and drilling steel takes work. Covering the rear wall with screwed-in 3/4" plywood like Crip659 suggests would easily compensate for that stud-deficient wall (if it truly is stud-deficient) and #10 wood screws can easily hold up a cabinet and all contents unless you're filling it to the brim with law books.

I seriously doubt a sheet of plywood is needed here. There's probably another stud, but just what's there is enough.

Buy a free-standing/floor-standing shelf unit less than 66" wide (48" seems to be the most likely at my local stores, a 30 and a 36 might also be an option) and set it in place. The 48" wire ones I just bought will do 800 lbs per shelf, so if you want to put a cabinet on them, they'll take it, and you can load them up with all the laundry products that fit without being in any danger of collapse.

@Ecnerwal That is certainly an option. But depending on room layout and the possibility of water on the floor, shelves that are not floor-standing may be preferred.

The metal post/wire type shelves are often used in mop-down applications, as they can stand in a puddle without turning to mush like MDF or wicking the water up to the stuff on the shelf, and the bottom shelf can be adjusted to allow sufficient clearance for mopping - so that particular argument is not strong.

Usually if studs are not in the right place to mount something, people use 3/4 plywood or 1x6s going across the studs.
There should be a stud in each corner and a good possibility of a hidden stud to the left.
If a stud finder does not find the third stud, can try pushing in a small nail through the drywall.  Can do this where you expect the second cabinet to cover.
Drywall is quite weak for holding weight up and people tend to add more weight than expected during planning stage.  Flat surfaces tend to be good for storing stuff.
Toggles are good but I would not trust them to hold weight forever.
